# Error when using dataTable jQuery plugin inside my asp.net mvc web application, "Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0. "

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables

I am working with the DataTable jquery plugin inside my asp.net mvc web application.

i have the following model class:-

```
public partial class Emp
    {
        public int EmpID { get; set; }
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public string LName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DeptID { get; set; }

        public virtual Dept Dept { get; set; }
    }
```

the following script:-

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "Home/AjaxHandler",
                "bProcessing": true,
                "aoColumns": [
                                { "sName": "FName"
                                    }
                                ,
                                { "sName": "LName" },
                                { "sName": "DeptID" }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

the following controller:-

```
    public ActionResult AjaxHandler(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
    {
        var allCompanies = t.Emps;

        var result = allCompanies.Select(c=> new {c.FName, c.LName, c.DeptID});
                   //  select new[] {  };

        return Json(new
        {
            sEcho = param.sEcho,
            iTotalRecords = allCompanies.Count(),
            iTotalDisplayRecords = allCompanies.Count(),
            aaData = result.ToList()
        },
                        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and here is the view:-

```
<table id="myDataTable" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>FName</th>
            <th>LName</th>
            <th>DeptID</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

but when i run the application i got the following error and all the data will be displayed as null:-

> DataTables warning: table id=myDataTable - Ajax error. For more
>   information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
>
> DataTables warning: table id=myDataTable - Requested unknown parameter
>   '0' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/4

[image]

Comment: what does returned JSON look like for `aData`? Seems it doesn't match what you declared in column definitions

Comment: @charlietfl can you adivce more on this please ? now i am returning three columns from my action method, as defined inside the columns definition..

Comment: sure, inspect the actual request in browser console and look at response body

Comment: @charlietfl here is the response from the action method call. {"sEcho":"1","iTotalRecords":2,"iTotalDisplayRecords":2,"aaData":[{"FName":"f1","LName":"l1","DeptID":1},{"FName":"f2","LName":"l2","DeptID":2}]}

Comment: and i am using datatable version 1.10.4 & jquery version 1.10.2...

Comment: I think problem might be using old API docs to set up column definitions. Example from one of my projects: `columns:[ { data: "id" }..`

Comment: ok i edited the script to use "columns" instead of "aoColumns" but still i am getting the same problem ...

Comment: using `data` instead of `sName`?

Comment: aha it worked, so seems that i was reading  old documentationfrom this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part

Comment: The API got a major overhaul for 1.10. likely to be lots of issues due to old tutorials

Comment: but i could not find any new tutorial ,, can you adivce ?

Comment: lots of examples in the docs, as well as API is well documented

Comment: can you provide some urls please? and i am looking mainly for strongly typed version of dataTable plugin that are more suited with asp.net mvc framework ...

Comment: what you use at back end is irrelevant. Browser doesn't know or care what language or framework is used at server. Maybe there are .net modules. Docs are easy to find in google

Comment: @charlietfl but in my case i am using the server-side version of the dataTables

Answer (score 1):

As stated you are using old initializers, try this instead

```
$('#myDataTable').dataTable({
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "Home/AjaxHandler",
    "processing": true,
    "columns": [
                { "data": "FName"},
                { "data": "LName" },
                { "data": "DeptID" }
    ]
});
```

Comment: ok it worked , but i am facing a problem when displaying a Date field inside my datTable plugin. for example i have a dattime field with value equal to "01/01/1980 01:02:04" but it will be dislayed as "/Date(315536524000)/" inside the dataTable